# undefined method 'sign_in' for rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

Hello so i keep getting this error, although i tried some of the solutions posted around here

**spec/support/devise.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
 config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
end
```

**accounts_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::AccountsController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET index no account" do
    it "has a 403 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(403)
    end
  end
  describe "GET index with account" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      sign_in @user
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::AccountsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
        #show user details
        raise if not current_user
        render json: { :user => current_user.as_json(:except=>[:created_at, :updated_at, :authorization_token, :provider, :uid, :id])}
        rescue
        render nothing: true, status: 403   
    end
```

Any ideas ? i'm blocked, the first test for 403 works, but then i just can't use the sign_in of devise ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the devise.rb files. The correct config lines were

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the config is not being run.
Make sure you have your `spec/support/devise.rb` included by something like

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

in `rails_helper.rb`

Or move these `config.include`s into `rails_helper` itself

Comment: None of these worked. .. but i did find the problem however. will post it below

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use This in your rails helper

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

To use sign_in method.